# Finding quarter or half wave plate in stuff

Tags: optics, laser

I've heard that we can find optic objects in some old stuff like DVD writers .
Do you know how I can get a quarter or half wave plate?
except buying it!!

Answer (score 2):

Such items would almost always be bonded to other optical components. For example, in glasses for 3D-cinema, $\lambda/4$-plates are bonded to polarizing filters, in order to produce left- and right-circularly polarized light.

You could try to make your own by stretching plastics.